# How to query all the records that have shared pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a column contains urls. Some (but not all) urls share the same domain. Ex: aaa.yahoo.com, bbb.yahoo.com, ccc.yahoo.com. These urls are stored in a unique field. Also, the same table has an auto-increment primary key.

What I need to do and need help on it is: Query all the urls that share the same domain name. Note that, there is no exact domain name that I can put in the query, a lot of the shared domain names available in the database and I want to query them all.

**EDIT:** 
This is the command I've tried but totally not sure as I don't have that much experience in SQL:

```
SELECT domainname FROM DB.TABLE
WHERE SUBSTRING(domainname, LOCATE('.', domainname))
IN(
    SELECT   domainname
    FROM     DB.TABLE
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(domainname, LOCATE('.', doaminname)) 
);
```

Comment: what is your table schema? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure if this statement is valid: `SELECT domainname from DB.TABLE where SUBSTRING(domainname, LOCATE('.', domainname) )
IN(
    SELECT   domainname
    FROM     DB.TABLE
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(domainname, LOCATE('.', doaminname)) 
  );` I have tried it but it took too much time, I aborted the execution. I don't have a lot of experience in SQL commands so I don't want to make any corruption for the DB.

Comment: click "Edit" to update your question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not understanding you incorrectly...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`domainname`) AS 'occ'
    ,SUBSTRING(`domainname`,LOCATE('.',`domainname`)+1) AS 'domain'
FROM `the_table`
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`domainname`,LOCATE('.',`domainname`)+1)
HAVING `occ`>1
ORDER BY `occ` DESC,`domain` ASC
```

The `HAVING...` line will filter out the domains that have only 1 occurence in the table.

---

### EDIT:

Speaking on behalf of your comments... Because you can not know which is domain in the following examples (unless you test the values against a huge list of country codes, domain extensions etc)

- domain.co.uk
- subdomain.domain.co

you can not programmatically detect those. If you're planning to rely on extension or the country extension, that won't work either. What you can do is get a smart sorting and pick the ones by your eyes, that is unless you go about the above mentioned solution.

So, for example,

```
SELECT
    `id`
    ,`d` AS 'domain'
    ,IF(CHAR_LENGTH(`d`)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(`d`,'.',''))=2,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(`d`,'.',1),'') AS 'f1'
    ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`d`,'.',-2),'.',1) AS 'f2'
    ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(`d`,'.',-1) AS 'f3'
FROM (
    SELECT
        `id`
        ,IF(CHAR_LENGTH(`domainname`)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(`domainname`,'.',''))>2,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(`domainname`,'.',-3),`domainname`) AS 'd'
    FROM `the_table`
    GROUP BY `d`
) t
ORDER BY `f3`,`f2`,`f1`
```

might help you to see it. Note that you can not group the result by `f2` and `f3` because you might have

- example1.yahoo.com
- example2.yahoo.com

but you might also have

- yahoo.com.br
- google.com.br

Comment: If this is a frequent operation it might be worth creating a new indexed column specifically for this purpose and populating it with the result of that `domain` expression. As an **important note**, this will not work with many TLDs like `bbc.co.uk` where that will get sorted under `co.uk` which is incorrect. A very thorough list of [public domain suffixes](http://publicsuffix.org/) is published for those that need to be certain of the proper domain name.

Comment: @tadman I was thinking about this while writing the query but I had to assume that the **domainname** values contain the www prefix or a subdomain. Possible extensions are huge in amount, on the other hand, but indexing a separate column, I think, is the way to go.

Comment: Your statement solved part of my problem. It gave me the domain name & how many times it appears. (Ex: 16, yahoo.com, 20, msn.com, 17, google.com). Now, I have to query each domain with `like '%domainname'` & see all the values that contains this specific domain name & delete them manually & leave the parent domain only, which is the value I need (ex: yahoo.com). Unless if there is a better way you can suggest to achieve this (They are a lot of rows). I have little experience in SQL, so excuse my questions.

Comment: Also, not all the stored value in the column domainname are with child domain. Some of them are correct & don't have child domain (ex: live.com). Your query included output like: (100, com, 50,net) which are not duplicated domain name. These are extensions but occurred after the first dot because there was no child domain from the first place & they are valid for me & don't want to query them. All the stored domain names are without `www`.

Comment: You can not detect if it's a domain extension or the domain itself in certain situations unless you list all the possible extensions and country codes explicitly (and use these with `REGEXP` or `LIKE` functions). What you can do is sort the records so that you can easily see duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE operand. Something like:

```
SELECT domainname from DB.TABLE where domainname LIKE '%.yahoo.com';
```

It will returns all sub domains of yahoo.com. '%' is wildcard for multiple characters, use underscore '_' for single character.

Comment: As I have mentioned. I don't know the domain name in advanced. It can be yahoo, msn, google. I have a lot of domain names. So, my question is how to make a query to get any multiple occurrence of a string before the domain name. (i.e, if the value inserted for once, no need to query it. I only need the multiple occurrence. Ex: aaa.yahoo.com, bbb.yahoo.com).

Comment: For that case, you should use regular expression (REGEXP) method. Check out here: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2337